# PowerShell in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have a project written in PowerShell and I want to create an interface for it using Visual Studio 2012. How can I load the .ps1 file in Solution Explorer? I have already run through these steps:

http://nickmeldrum.com/blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010

(the steps are for Visual Studio 2010 but I thought the settings shouldn't differ too much) but now I don't know what to do...I have to install some tools or something?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what's the issue here. Steps from the linked article should work with Visual Studio 2012 without any adjustments as far as I see. Make sure that you followed those steps correctly.

BTW, you may want to install ["PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2012"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e3f9d3bf-e630-4b3e-968a-f86ac67b836c) extension.